# JavaFX Text Change Event

Tags: textarea, javafx, addeventlistener

I designed a form in FXML document.I can handle keypress vs. events. But I need text change event.I'm using Netbeans 7.3 . There's three files in the projects: SampleControler, Sample.FXML and Sample.java. I found a code but I have not solved where to use it.

```
input.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override 
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {                
            System.out.println("Changed.");              
        }    
    });
```

My TextArea code is:

```
<TextArea layoutX="10" layoutY="50" maxHeight="125" minHeight="125" maxWidth="570" minWidth="570" editable="true" fx:id="input" prefWidth="570" prefHeight="125" />
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your controller associeted to your fxml, get your TextArea, and you will can do :

yourTextArea.textproperty().addListener ...

```
public class Example implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The varibale name on the controller need to have the same name like the fx:id in the fxml